# Trying to add this script tag to my next.js app but am having Trouble

Tags: email, next.js, head

To start using EmailJS on your website just paste the following code snippet before closing tag, with the correct user ID:
Then i have to import it in index.html file but there isn't a index.html can someone please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2/dist/email.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
      emailjs.init("YOUR_USER_ID");
   })();
</script>

    return (
      <ProductProvider>
        <div className="main-wrapper">
          <Head>
            <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2/dist/email.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
      emailjs.init("YOUR_USER_ID")
   })();
</script>
        </Head>
          <BusinessTheme ThemeClass="demo1" />
        </div>
      </ProductProvider>
    );
}

   const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../node_modules/emailjs-com'),
  { ssr: false }
);
    )
```

How do i find Email js file to import?
I am getting error that emailjs is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Next.JS is 2 side running (Server and client sideded). You can install emailJs on dependency instead on cdn. (Maybe cause of occurrence emailJS undefined)

```
$ npm install emailjs-com --save
```

And if emailJS running on client side (javascript), u can use dynamic import on next js and disable ssr [Dynamic Import NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).
Thanks